# Show if the function $f(x)=x^3+x^2-2$ is surjective and injective

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$$f(x)=x^3+x^2-2$$ we need to show for this function.

My try:

So for surjectivity we have $$D_f^{-1}\rightarrow Z_f^{-1} = Z_f\rightarrow D_f$$

$$D_f....\text{is the domain}$$
$$Z_f.... \text{is the range}$$

I tried to get $f^{-1}$ for this function and couldn't calculate it. Then I put it in wolfram mathematica and a very complicated expression showed. So I don't know how to tackle this problem another way without the $f^{-1}$. Maybe I just don't know how to calculate it.

Comment: Hello! This notation $D_f$ and $Z_f$ seems to be unique to your instructor, so people here may not recognize it.

Comment: @hunter I editet and showed the terminoligy

Comment: Observe that $f(0)=f(-1)=-2$. So $f$ is not injective.

Comment: @AnuragA Is it true that it's a different kind of proof to show that a function "is injective" and that a function "is not injective" ?

Comment: @BiliDebili not sure what you mean by different proof to show it is "injective" and "not injective"??

Comment: @AnuragA Looks like I misunderstood my notes from lectures.  The proffessor was mentioning something about two different kinds to show that something "is not" and that something "is".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=\pm\infty$, it follows from the intermediate value theorem that $f$ is surjective.

But $f$ is *not* injective, as it is decreasing on $\left[-\frac23,0\right]$ and increasing elsewhere.

Comment: So in school we have done the following to show that a function is surjective: $f^{-1}(f(x))=\{identity in range}$. I like your solution, I am just wondering what is your view on the kind of proof that we use in school.

Comment: It's fine, if you can find the inverse of $f$. That's not the case here.